# How to run Powershell in SSIS using excute process task with variable?

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package and I need to run Powershell to get some data. I used an Excute Process Task in SSIS and put `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` in executable and it works perfectly. Now I want to set up a variable to get the work done. I created a variable and put the datatype strin and set the value as `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.

Then  I went to expressions in the Executable Process task and make it 'executable' and put `@[User::Powershell_Location]` there. But I don't know what should I put in the Executable in process menu.

Comment: what is driving the decision to use PowerShell to get data rather the SSIS tools themselves?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the expression tab of Execute Process Task Editor and then assign an expression to 'Executable' and optionally to 'Arguments', if you have any arguments to pass in. See attached

[image]